# java udp client couldnt receive packet send by server

Tags: java

from java udp programming every thing is working fine,except the server responding to the client is not detected.i.e sending data to server is ok, server received data and respond back to the client.The problem is the data not receiving to client.
My local port used is 501
server listening port is 500, and i send data to 500 to server and wait the connection at 501 at client. The code can illustrate this:
this is the recieving thread.. Dont know where goes wrong!  Note i am useing the online server.

```
String myipAddress = "10.100.69.174";
String SendingIp = "108.163.180.54";
String sendinPort = "500";
String myRecievePortNo="501";

public void run() 
    {
        try {

             recievingSocket = new DatagramSocket(Integer.parseInt(myRecievePortNo), InetAddress.getByName(myipAddress));
            while (true) 
            {

                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket recievingPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                recievingSocket.receive(recievingPacket);
                String mydata = new String(data, 0, data.length);
                 System.out.printf("Hello recieve"+mydata);
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception EX) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Message" + EX, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    }






//this section is call when user click the send button
public void sendData(String toServer) {
    try
    {
        DatagramSocket sendingSocket = new DatagramSocket(Integer.parseInt(myRecievePortNo));
        byte[] data = toServer.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendingPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, InetAddress.getByName(SendingIp), Integer.parseInt(sendinPort));
        sendingSocket.send(sendingPacket);
        sendingSocket.close();
    }
    catch (Exception EX) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sending Error :" + EX, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }


}
```

Comment: You didn't post all of the code, so it's hard to tell, but from the variable names, it looks like the server may be sending to the port that it is listening on, instead of the port that the client is listening on.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding both sockets to 501 and you are sending to 500. The sending port at the client is the receiving port at the server, but you have confused yourself by only having one pair of variables. Split this into two classes.

Comment: i want to make clear.. Server is listening at port 500; client send the request at 500 using local port no 501; so the server receives the port client port 501 from where data is send to server. The client is now waiting on port 501. This is the case: now receiving and sending class are different classes. Is it possible to create two socket each for sending and receiving. The code tested and is ok at LAN.

Comment: @rajmaharjan Why do you think you need two sockets each? You don't. If what you say about the port numbers is correct, which doesn't agree with the code you posted, you now seem to have a network connectivity problem in whatever non-LAN network you are now using and haven't told us about, which is off topic for SO.

Comment: Thanks for replying!! i deleted one socket. oh.. this is online server and client communications. If there is the connectivity problem then the server couldnt receive the data and send too. I stated this problems on the first. I used tcpdump to sniff the packet at the server side and packet has been seen that server responds. The only thing is not receiving on the client. I am not getting any errors but packet is lost as send by server.

Comment: @rajmaharjan You keep leaving out important information. There is no code here to send a reply back to the client. It is impossible to help you when you keep suppressing significant parts of the question.

Comment: yes!! successfully.. Does NAT play role here? or something else??